# Reliable decent affiliate system to help with selling my software

Tags: software-development

I write and sell my software on my website, but I'm better at writing software then selling it. I'd like to give my customers the opportunity to sell my software and get a cut of the price for doing so. But I need a system to do this, and it might be better if a third party is involved to help manage it. But whenever I search for affiliate systems they seem to be all encompassing, and dodgy with many complaints about them.

Is there a more limited solution that just allows me to setup an affiliate system for my customers?

Answer (score 1):

When you search for "affiliate systems" what your getting is software results for running your own in house affiliate programs where you are responsible for all payments,taxes, and other details. I think a solution that fits what your looking for is to become a vendor in a affiliate network as they will handle those issues simplifying things for a fee that comes directly out during the payment processing. Some examples would be Clickbank, JVzoo.com/sellers, and Gumroad.com. Amazon isn't particularly thought of as a affiliate network but they do have a affiliate program and host downloadable software. You'll have to read through the terms and conditions of each and potentially you could look up others as there are many affiliate networks with pros and cons to each one.

http://www.clickbank.com/corp/platform-overview/product-creators/
https://aws.amazon.com/partners/aws-marketplace/

Comment: actaully it was the inhouse affiliate programs I was looking for !

Comment: Then consider this a possible alternative solution.